# how to fix Facebook JSDK that sometimes loads twice, once, or doesnt load at all?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im using facebook javaSDK for my website and I have a weird problem.
When I load the website with "internet explorer" it always runs fine.
When I load the website with firefox it always loads TWICE, and when I use chrome the JSDK sometimes loads once and sometimes not loads at all , giving me the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined ".
I tried using asynchronous loading for the SDK but still the same problem.
btw I have firebug on firefox, could that be the reason the JSDK loads twice?

this is the code for loading the jssdk

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '108437552626598', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});


};

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
```

And Im trying to use FB.getlogin, im trying to integrete facebook opengraph in Wordpress site. Ive out my script right after I finish loading the main content
This is the code

```
             </div><!-- end #content -->


<script type="text/javascript"      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
 if (response.status == 'connected') {
alert('in');
window.facebooklogin = 'true';
    window.myValue = response.authResponse.accessToken;  
window.myId = response.authResponse.userID;
$('.userimage img').attr('src','http://graph.facebook.com/' + window.myId +         '/picture');
 $.ajax({ url: 'http://ballvids.com/check/admin_checkuser.php',
     data: {action: window.myId},
 dataType:'json',
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
    if (output.message == 'true'){
        $('.thumbnail   img').attr('src',"http://ballvids.com/images/on2.png");
        alert(window.myValue);
        FB.api('/me/video.watches?video=<?php echo   urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID));?>&access_token='+window.myValue,'post',function(response) {
             if (!response || response.error) {
            alert(response.error.message);
            } else {
            alert(response.id);
            postID=response.id;
            showStuff('removeTimeline');
            }  
                });
    }else{

        $('.thumbnail img').attr('src',"http://ballvids.com/images/off2.png");
    }

        }
});
}else{
    alert('inside2');
    $('.thumbnail img').attr('src',"http://ballvids.com/images/off2.png");
    window.facebooklogin = 'false';
}
```

},true);

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any example code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Added example code, the issue occures when im trying to use FB.getLoginStatus

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `FBLoginStatus()`, inside the `fbAsyncInit`

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : APP_ID,
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, true);
};
```

If you have problems with the cached object returned from the `FB.getLoginStatus()` you have to pass a second parameter `true`.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Thanks!.My code is actually built in a way that fb.getlogin is in a different page, but ill I try to unite them. Do you have any idea why it loads twice on firefox?

Comment: @user1108310 you need to add a channel.

Answer (score 1):

> When I load the website with firefox it always loads TWICE,

Try setting up a channel.html file and referencing it on initialization.

> and when I use chrome the JSDK sometimes loads once and sometimes not loads at all , giving me the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined ".

*If* you had your calls to FB methods wrapped into window.fbAsyncInit that would not be possible, because that callback would never be called if the SDK wasn’t loaded. Conclusion: You didn’t, but instead you put your FB.getLoginStatus call somewhere else (which you still haven’t shown us in your code yet).

Comment: Thanks! Ill the fb.getlogin code, but I dont think that its the source of the problem since it always works on InternetExplorer.

Comment: __Flawed__ scripting logic doesn’t get _right_ just because it may work in some particular browser …

Comment: Added the script of FB.getlogin, please see if you can find whats wrong in my code \: